# How to get full object data in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I tried to get some infos with google but I couldn't find an answer to my question...

I'm trying to access MS Teams from an ASP.net web app. As a first step I've loaded a list of my joined teams:

```
var teams = await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
   .Request()
   .GetAsync();
```

The 'problem' that I have is that all of the interesting properties within those Team objects are null (like Channels or PrimaryChannel).

Getting the list of channels from a specific team is not much of a problem:

```
var channels = await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels
   .Request()
   .GetAsync();
```

But how can I combine these two things? I mean, how can I get a list of my joined teams that already contains the underlying channels? There has to be a way to get that Channels property filled, right?

Thanks a lot!

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

@Vibrationz, You need to make two calls. One to get joined Teams and one to get the Channels of the Teams.